# SELECT last row, but only if column value is the expected one

Tags: sql

My Table

```
---------------------
id | userid | name
---------------------
0     1       John
1     2       Ellen
2     1       Peter
---------------------
```

This table shows, that `John` has changed his name to `Peter` (same `userid` - same person) as `id`=2 is newer record than id=`0`

Now... I may want to check whether `John` is the last name of `userid`=1. I need to SELECT `id` of the LAST row WHERE `userid`=1, but only if `name`=`John`. And since `name` in the last row with `userid`=1 is not `John` in this particular case, NULL should be returned. How do I do that? With single SQL command. Thanks

I am using Sqlite3 by the way, some advanced MySQL stuff may not work in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one method is to use `order by` and limit the results to one row:

```
select (case when name = 'John' then name end)
from t
where userid = 1
order by id desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This uses the `fetch first` clause because it is Standard SQL.  Your database might have another method.

Comment: That answers the question, thank you very much!